# How to use .dae files in android?

Tags: android, 3d, collada

The functionality needed is scrolling like Live Images. There is a direct support for apple for .DAE, the support for the same is practically missing in android. Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556524/3d-model-basics-in-arkit-arcore-development